# How to stop SUM function getting called for each row MySQL pivot

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 2 tables: 1 for customer orders and another one for customer returns. Both tables have a customer id column and a total column.

I'm trying to make a pivot table where I subtract total returns from total orders. The problem is that when there are more than 1 rows of returns the **SUM** function gets called for each row.

This is the query that I`m using.

```
SELECT

( (Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 3 THEN orders.total END) - 

(Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(return_date) = 3 THEN returns.total END) ) AS May

FROM orders

INNER JOIN returns ON orders.customer = returns.customer

WHERE customer = ?
```

Could it have something to do with grouping?

Comment: I would need to see a create statement for your tables to be certain, but I suspect the issue is with your join causing a cross product.  Try the query using "Select * ..." instead and see what your results look like.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why join here at all?  Why not just `(SELECT SUM(total) FROM orders WHERE customer = ? AND order_date BETWEEN ? AND ?) - (SELECT SUM(total) FROM returns WHERE customer = ? AND order_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final query that I used:

```
SELECT

 ( (Sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 1 THEN total END) / 100) - 

(SELECT COALESCE( ( SUM(total) / 100), 0) FROM returns 
 WHERE customer = orders.customer AND MONTH(return_date) = 1) ) , 0) AS May

FROM orders

WHERE customer = ?
```

It uses **COALESCE** to account for the possibility of having no returns.